# How to set colums to be comboboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have populated a DataGridView from a dataTable. I wan't some columns to appear as comboboxes, dropdowns. How do I do this?
My code sofar:

```
DataTable dt = dataBase.getData();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
//set some columns to comboboxes
```

Comment: for what purpose are you trying to do so, for filtering?

Comment: you need to customize your datagridview

Comment: You can add this on the aspx side !!

Comment: I wan't to set the values easier. Like, if there are integers in a column, i want to use a `numericUpDown` to set them. I use MySQL.

Comment: If this is winforms please add the tag and see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733114/add-all-elements-of-array-to-datagridview-rows-except-one thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the designer you can set that a column is of type:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
```

or you can set it programmatically

Answer (score 2):

You should set property `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and then create each column with respective template

Answer (score 0):

You need to design column in datagridview in designer ,Change the type to required column to DataGridViewcombox

And then add value of this column from desired DataTable column