# Copy ComboBox Dataset to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

(Using C# Visual Studio 2015, Windows Forms)

I have a list of strings that I want to show in a DataGridView (DGV).

Each row in the DGV will have:

- column[0]:  String value from list (*ColumnType: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn*)
- column[1]:  A blank cell (user will enter data here) (*ColumnType: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn*)
- column[2]:  A ComboBox (*ColumnType: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn*)

Every ComboBox in each record will have identical items (the same DataSet) and I retrieve these from a SQL query to my Access Database (accdb).

My main problem is that I need to identify the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` of each ComboBox, and I can't figure out how to do that. My current code just tries to copy the DataTable `results` into the ComboBox, but I'm getting the error:
`System.ArgumentException.DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.`

[image]

And it repeats for every value of every ComboBox in the DataGridView. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
     DataTable results = new DataTable();

     //Identify the Connection String
     connection.ConnectionString = dbQuery.connStr;

     //SQL Statement to retrieve ComboBox Items
     string sql = @"SELECT ID, DESCRIP FROM tbl_setpoints_categories ORDER BY DESCRIP ASC";

     //Create a new ComboBox (this is for testing purposes)
     ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = sql;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            results.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            results.Columns.Add("DESCRIP", typeof(string));
            results.Load(reader);

            //For testing purposes...
            cb.ValueMember = "ID";
            cb.DisplayMember = "DESCRIP";
            cb.DataSource = results;

            if (!reader.IsClosed)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }


        //Loop through the list and add each into an array of objects
        //This array will be added as a DataGridView row
        foreach (string spName in spList)
        {

            //My Latest Edit, but still produces same error
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cbCell.ValueMember = "ID";
            cbCell.DisplayMember = "DESCRIP";
            cbCell.DataSource = results;
            //End Latest Edit

            object[] row = new object[3];
            row[0] = spName.ToString();
            row[1] = "";
            row[2] = cbCell;  //From Latest Edit (was: results)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

**EDIT:** I just checked to see if my query was pulling records by adding this line:
`MessageBox.Show(results.Rows.Count.ToString());` 
And I received the correct number of records

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654829/datagridviewcomboboxcell-binding-value-is-not-valid

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this may clear things up. Unfortunately a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` is NOT a column of `ComboBox`controls. So the lines below won’t work as a `DataGridView` column.

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.ValueMember = "ID";
cb.DisplayMember = "DESCRIP";
cb.DataSource = results;
```

The `DataGridView` has a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` which unfortunately is a little more challenging to implement than a regular `ComboBox`. So to help visualize this, I made a drawing to show what I am describing.

[image]

Above you can see the output from the code below. I used the button click to place a breakpoint to display the two `DataTables`. The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` `DataSource` is a `DataTable` with the different “Set Point Types” and is displayed on the right showing “Id” and “Set Point Types” 0-14. These are the items that the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` uses as a `DataSource.`

The convenient part is that once you set the `DataSource` for this column you do not have to update this with every new/existing cell. The column will build the `ComboBoxCells` automatically. When you create the `DataTable` for the main `DataGridView` with all the data, you would assume that the cells where the combo box column is needs to have ALL the values. But these values would simply be a single string that matches one of the items in combo box (hopefully). So the `DataGridView` `DataTable` (not the `DataGridView` column) needs to make this column a string (not a combo box)  as it can contain only ONE value from the different “Set Point Types” types. The convenient aspect is that even though it is a string and not a combo box, if it matches an existing item in the combo box then it will display that item.

Below is the code that was used for the picture above.

First set the `DataGridView` columns with two text columns then the last column is the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. The `GetComboColumn` method returns a `DatGridViewComboBoxColumn` with the different items for the combo box. Here the pertinent properties are `DataPropertyName`, `DisplayMemeber` and `ValueMember`, these identify which columns to use from the `DataSource`. Below that is a method to add a text column to the `DataTable`.

Finally, we get a `DataTable` for the `DataGridView` with some test data for testing. Hope this helps.

```
DataTable allData;
DataTable comboTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SetDGVColumns();
  allData = GetAllData();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = allData;
}

private DataTable GetAllData() {
  DataTable data = new DataTable();
  data.Columns.Add("Set Point Name", typeof(string));
  data.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
  data.Columns.Add("Set Point Type", typeof(string));  // <-- NOTE: this is a string- not a combo box

  data.Rows.Add("nai_m2_no2", "Description 0", "Set Point Type 4");
  data.Rows.Add("nao_enth_no3", "Description 1", "Set Point Type 13");
  data.Rows.Add("nai_m2_no4", "Description 2", "Set Point Type 4");
  data.Rows.Add("nai_m2_no5", "Description 3", "Set Point Type 11");
  data.Rows.Add("nai_m2_no6", "Description 4", "Set Point Type 3");
  data.Rows.Add("nai_m2_no7", "Description 5", "Set Point Type 2");
  return data;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void SetDGVColumns() {
  AddTextCol("Set Point Name");
  AddTextCol("Description");
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetComboColumn()); // <-- THIS DataGridView Column needs to be a combo box column
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GetComboColumn() {
  comboTable = new DataTable();
  comboTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  comboTable.Columns.Add("Set Point Type", typeof(string));
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    comboTable.Rows.Add(i, "Set Point Type " + i);
  }
  // we now have a data table to use as a data source for the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
  // make a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and set it properties
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn typeCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  typeCol.Width = 150;
  typeCol.DataPropertyName = "Set Point Type";  //<-- needs to match the DataTable column name you want to display - in this case 'Set Point Type'
  typeCol.HeaderText = "Set Point Type";
  typeCol.ValueMember = "Set Point Type";
  typeCol.DisplayMember = "Set Point Type";
  typeCol.Name = "Set Point Type";
  typeCol.DataSource = comboTable;
  return typeCol;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void AddTextCol(string colInfo) {
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn TextCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  TextCol.DataPropertyName = colInfo;
  TextCol.HeaderText = colInfo;
  TextCol.Name = colInfo;
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(TextCol);
}
```