# Winform EF Data Grid View Databinding results in DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, datagridview

Slightly related to [DataGridViewComboBoxCell Binding - "value is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654829/datagridviewcomboboxcell-binding-value-is-not-valid) - I have an EF Database First project wherein I have three tables (and of course matching class representations):

> AssayHistoricalValue
>
> AssayResultType
>
> AssayUsageType

The "Type" tables have Name descriptions in them, but the DataGridView needs to select Names from a ComboBox and store the ID itself in the DB behind the scenes.

I set all this up in the Edit Columns UI that makes adjustments to the Designer code - and everything looks proper:

[image]

Then, when I realized an error was being thrown:

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

I realized a few others had this problem (such as the post I linked above) and online in other places. Some said suppressing the error as such worked for them, but this just results in an error along the lines of:

> 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is
>   set.'

At the line where it does Items.Add below:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //Avoid error of data bound combobox cells
    if (e.Exception.Message == "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.")
    {
        object value = ConstantsGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        if (!((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)ConstantsGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Contains(value))
        {
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)ConstantsGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Add(value);
            e.ThrowException = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I tried just using the "AssayResultType" or Usage type object in the columns (which it prepops with when you add the the entity object/table you're trying to update) - and that doesn't work either.

I could probably more easily write LINQ statements and the like to populate all this as the structure is pretty simply, but I felt like the bindings set up here should do most the work for something like this. Thoughts on what might be up here?

SQL for 2 of tables in question (in case that's needed - if we can get 1 relationship working with Result Type the Usage Type should be fine too as it's the same really):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayHistoricalValue](
    [AssayHistoricalValueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AssayResultTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssayUsageTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MeanValue] [float] NOT NULL,
    [StandardDeviationValue] [float] NOT NULL,
    [RValue] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAssayHistoricalValue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AssayHistoricalValueId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayHistoricalValue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAssayHistoricalValue_tblAssayResultType] FOREIGN KEY([AssayResultTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblAssayResultType] ([AssayResultTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayHistoricalValue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAssayHistoricalValue_tblAssayResultType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayHistoricalValue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAssayHistoricalValue_tblAssayUsageType] FOREIGN KEY([AssayUsageTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblAssayUsageType] ([AssayUsageTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayHistoricalValue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAssayHistoricalValue_tblAssayUsageType]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayResultType](
    [AssayResultTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssayId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAssayResultType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AssayResultTypeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayResultType]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAssayResultType_tblAssay] FOREIGN KEY([AssayId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblAssay] ([AssayId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAssayResultType] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAssayResultType_tblAssay]
GO
```

Comment: What is default value of `AssayResultTypeId` in `AssayHistoricalValue` table? Does it allows to be `null`?

Comment: It doesn't allow NULLS for the AssayResultType nor the AssayUsageType IDs - HistoricalValue Id is of course the PK and is of IDENTITY type.

Comment: What is the type of  `Id` fields?

Comment: Using Ints for all the Id fields - PK is set for AssayHistoricalValueId

Comment: I'll throw my SQL for 2 of the 3 tables up above (should work fine if we get just 1 type to work) - only real difference is the classes are generated without the "tbl-" prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the picture you allow user to add new records in the `DataGridView`. If this is a case, then DataGridView will try to bind default value for `AssayResultTypeId` column(`integer => 0`) to the `DataSource` of correspondent combobox column.

As workaround you can try disable `Allow add rows` option in your `DataGridView`.

Or add "empty" record to the binding source of the combobox column

```
var defaultResult = new AssayResultType { Id = 0, Name = "Please select type..." };

// Insert because you want keep it on the top of the list
resultTypesCollection.Insert(0, defaultResult);
```