# Binding List of Lists to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

For my current problem I want to create a DataGridView and use a list of objects as the datasource.

The problem I'm having is that the objects itself contains two lists, which are supposed to fill combobox columns. The DataGridView should contain three columns, each corresponding to my sample object below. The first column is a simple text column, while the other two are combo box columns.

Currently I'm receiving the error:

> System.ArgumentException: The value DataGridViewComboBoxCell is invalid.

I've been looking for other solutions on SO, but can't seem to get it right.

```
    public class SampleObject
    {
        public SampleObject(string name, IList<TimeSpan> startTimes, IList<Activity> completedActivities)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.StartTimes = startTimes;
            this.CompletedActivities = completedActivities;
        }

        public string Name { get; }

        public IList<TimeSpan> StartTimes { get; }

        public IList<Activity> CompletedActivities { get; }
    }
```

Activity object:

```
    public class Activity
    {
        public Activity(string activityName)
        {
            ActivityName = activityName;
        }

        public string ActivityName { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ActivityName;
        }
    }
```

And the code for adding the columns to my grid:

```
private void FillGrid()
    {
        sampleGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        var columnName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            DataPropertyName = nameof(SampleObject.Name),
            HeaderText = "Name",
            Width = 160,
            ReadOnly = true
        };
        sampleGrid.Columns.Add(columnName);

        var columnStartTimes = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        {
            ValueType = typeof(TimeSpan),
            HeaderText = "StartTimes",
            Width = 120,
            ReadOnly = false
        };
        sampleGrid.Columns.Add(columnStartTimes);

        var columnCompletedActivities = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        {
            ValueType = typeof(Activity),
            HeaderText = "Completed activities",
            Width = 120,
            ReadOnly = false

        };
        sampleGrid.Columns.Add(columnCompletedActivities);
    }
```

And populating the grid:

```
List<SampleObject> myObjects = GetSampleObjectsBasedOnValue(value);

sampleGrid.DataSource = myObjects;

FillComboBoxesInDGV(myObjects);
```

Method for filling the comboboxes:

```
        private void FillComboBoxesInDGV(IList<SampleObject> sampleObjects)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sampleObjects.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = sampleGrid.Rows[i];

                var firstBox = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                firstBox.DataSource = sampleObjects[i].StartTimes;

                var secondBox = row.Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                secondBox.DataSource = sampleObjects[i].CompletedActivities;
            }
        }
```

Comment: There appears to be some confusion as to “what” the combo boxes should contain. Example; you have a list of objects. When you “bind” the list of objects to the grid and set each column’s `DataPropertyName` to one of the properties of the object, this works for primitive types. However, if the property in the object is another object or “collection” (like another list) then the grid is NOT going to display this list in a combo box even if you set the `DataPropertyName`. This makes sense and there are ways to fix it to make it work. However, in your description…

Comment: Each combo box MAY have different values. Therefore, on each row in the grid, each combo box “could” contain different values. Because of this, Making a “single” `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` WONT WORK in this case. Unless you add ALL the :”start times” from ALL the rows into the combo box column, you are almost guaranteed to get the error you are getting which is saying that one of the “start times” in the data is NOT one of the items in the combo boxes list of items.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want ALL the combo boxes to contain the same items OR each combo box may have different items as they will require two different approaches.

Comment: @JohnG thanks for the reply. Yes every start times list in each row can be different.

Comment: Since you are using the `List<SampleObject>` as a `DataSource` to the grid, then AFTER the grid is bound to the list, you will need to loop through the GRID rows, grab the appropriate `SampleObject` for that row  and set each `DataGridComboBoxCell`’s `DataSource` to the appropriate “StartTimes” list or “CompleteActivites” list. You should also “remove” setting the columns `DataPropertyName` except for the “Name” column. Also, setting the “whole” grid to “ReadOnly” `sampleGrid.ReadOnly = true;` is going to make the combo boxes unchangeable.

Comment: With that said, and before you jump down that rabbit hole to add different values to each combo box… I have to ask… IS there a relationship between the combo boxes? Example from the sample code… when a user selects a different “TimeSpan” value, “should” the values in the “CompletedActivities” combo box change? If this is the case, then more work will be required as this would mean changing the value in a combo box base on the value of another combo box. This is a little more challenging.

Comment: The point being, it may be prudent to fully understand how you want these combos to “change” if at all. This is not clear. If the data is static and you have problems adding the values to the combo boxes, I can post a simple example of adding different values to each combo box.

Comment: I'm going to update my code in a minute according to what you just wrote. I dont get an error anymore, however I cannot use the comboboxes, as they have no values currently. The data I'm using is not static and is based of a combobox outside the DataGridView. Think of it as selecting a location, to which I populate the datagridview over and over at runtime.

Comment: As in each time the combobox value outside the datagridview changes.

Comment: If the data in the grid “changes” each time the “outside” combo box changes (with a new `List<SampleObject>`) AND the data is static, then what I described should work. What you posted appears to work.

Comment: Ah you are right. It appears to work. Thanks for the help! Currently still receiving an error when selecting an item in the second combobox (which actually contains a list of objects with overridden ToString() method). I get a DataError saying it can't parse from string to my object. As I only want to display some information in that row and don't want to use the object in the combo box for any other type of processing, would just catching the DataError and basically ignore it be fine?

Comment: I might just be able to fix that by parsing the values in the combobox to string beforehand and not using the object type as ValueType.

Comment: It happens after I select an item in the combobox and select any other cell in that row afterwards.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow, I do not get any errors as you describe with your posted code. Can you post what you are are taking about “parsing” some values? as this is not shown in the code. Also, your comment… _”… catching the DataError and basically ignore it be fine?”_ .. ignoring a grids `DataError` is NEVER a good idea.

Comment: I updated my code based on my current solution and error. As in parsing, I was under the impression the ToString method is called by default on an object (if there is one). But this might only be for listviews.

Comment: The data does not need to be converted from a string back to an object, because I won't be needing that object anymore as it's only purpose is giving information.

Comment: This kind of structure is handled in a Master/Detail view. Is not clear how you are assigning, in SampleObject, an `IList<string>` to a Property that is defined as `IList<Activity>`.

Answer (score 0):

I still not sure why you do not keep the original `IList<string>` `CompletedActivities` instead of introducing the `Activity` class? Using the list in this manner worked in my tests.

However, since you did use the class `Activity`, I would assumed it would work as expected. However, I ran into the same issue you described. After some hair pulling (and I don’t have much), I found some help from the SO post… [DataGridViewComboBoxCell Binding - “value is not valid”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654829/datagridviewcomboboxcell-binding-value-is-not-valid) … this was not obvious to me and I am guessing you also, thinking that overriding the `Activity` class’s `ToString` method would be enough. This is obviously not the case.

It appears that setting the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns`’s `ValueMember` property to the name of the property in the `Activity` class should eliminate the error.

```
var columnCompletedActivities = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn {
    HeaderText = "Completed activities",
    ValueMember = "ActivityName",
    Width = 120,
};
sampleGrid.Columns.Add(columnCompletedActivities);
```

I hope this works for you.